# Explain what are the projections of the point $P(a,b,c)$ on the planes of the coordinate system.

Tags: analytic-geometry

I want to explain what are the projections of the point $P(a,b,c)$ on the planes of the coordinate system.
the meaning is that if it on $XY$ plane so it will be $P(a,b,0)$ and so on?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. The $XY$ plane is the plane $Z=0$. So, to project a point onto this plane, you simply replace the point's $Z$-coordinate by zero. In other words, the point $(a,b,c)$ projects to $(a,b,0)$. The $YZ$ and $ZX$ planes are similar, of course.